# How to find vm in particular folder using pyvmomi

Tags: python-2.7, vmware, pyvmomi, pyvimeo

**Hi I am new in python and I am exploring pyvmomi. Here I want to fetch vm info.Like I have one data center i.e "DataCenter1"
        In that data center there are two folders LinuxServer and WindowsServer these folder contains vms.So I want to fetch vm name with their respective folder names**

```
    DataCenter1
    |
    |----LinuxServer
    |    |---RHEL-VM
    |    |---Ubuntu-VM
    |
    |----WindowsServer
    |    |---win2k12r2-VM
    |    |---win2k8r2-VM
```

**My code:**

```
    from pyvim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
    import ssl

    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    connect = SmartConnect(host="172.0.0.0",user="root",pwd="****",port=int("443"),sslContext=context)

    datacenter = connect.content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]
    print (datacenter)
    vms = datacenter.vmFolder.childEntity
    for i in vms:
        print(i.name)
        #Here I want to fetch vm name and their respective folder names
    Disconnect(c)
```

Here I am able to fetch all vm names but I want to fetch folder name of respective vm.
Is there any method ?
Can you please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you will get parent name of that vm means i.e your folder name if it exist.

```
from pyvim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
import ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
connect = SmartConnect(host="172.0.0.0",user="root",pwd="****",port=int("443"),sslContext=context)

datacenter = connect.content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]
print (datacenter)
vms = datacenter.vmFolder.childEntity
for vm in vms:
    print(vm.parent.name)
Disconnect(c)
```

Comment: This code won't work because `pyvim` doesn't exist, so it triggers a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvim'`. The module [is named `pyVim` instead](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/tree/master/pyVim), i.e. capital `V`. See also the other answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I use **python3.6**, full example below. It implement login vsphere and print every virtual machine name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# encoding: utf-8

from pyVim import connect
import ssl


def login():
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    si = connect.SmartConnect(host='192.168.0.1', user='root', pwd='password',
                              sslContext=ssl_context)
    print(si)
    print('\nHello World!\n')
    print('If you got here, you authenticted into vCenter.')
    data_center = si.content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]
    vms = data_center.vmFolder.childEntity
    for vm in vms:
        print(vm.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    login()
```

result:

```
'vim.ServiceInstance:ServiceInstance'

Hello World!

If you got here, you authenticted into vCenter.
sclautoesxd12v03
sclautoesxd12v04
sclautoesxd12v07
sclautoesxd12v09
sclautoesxd12v11
sclautoesxd12v12
sclautoesxd12v13
sclautoesxd12v16
sclautoesxd12v17
sclautoesxd12v01
sclautoesxd12v02
sclautoesxd12v05
sclautoesxd12v06
sclautoesxd12v08
sclautoesxd12v10
sclautoesxd12v14
sclautoesxd12v15
```